# Receiving "Handling input offset" message during db sync 3.1.1.3 update - going on 20 hours now. Is this normal?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Performing db sync update to 3.1.1.3 and waiting while server processes fix.  Currently receiving Handling input offset message as part of SQL update, been running for approximately 20 hours now.  Is this behavior normal and to be expected?  If yes, what exactly is the update doing that would take this long?  Perhaps restoring the cexplorer db from latest snapshot would have been a better update method.

Thanks

Comment: Highly advise restoring from a snapshot. I suspect syncing from scratch would take a week or more.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Thank you for the input here.